# Integrating Facebook login (oauth) with existing grails application using spring-security-core plugin

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have an existing grails application that uses spring-security plugin for authentication. I would like to add Facebook connect/login which can be done via Oauth (3 legged). However, spring security plugin now does not support Oauth out of the box. Any suggestions on how to go about adding it? If you have done this before, examples would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'd be interested to know what you did since I'm facing the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started out using this:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph

And then I had to switch to:

http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

because I needed more than just Facebook. However, neither integrate directly with Spring Security.  I was able to get it working though but taking the information Facebook returns and associating that to a particular User and then manually logging in through the Spring Security mechanism.  However, the solution is too much for an answer here.

I had planned on blogging about it but haven't had time.  If I do, I'll be sure and link to it here.  Sorry I can't be of more help.  But the Facebook Graph plugin is a very good place to start.

Comment: How did you handle the Spring Security password? Also, did you integrate the "remember me" functionality at all? Thanks!

Comment: If someone is interested you can find an example about how to integrate facebook-graph with the security plugin

http://alexduan.com/2011/08/23/grails-spring-security-facebook-in-depth-guide/

Answer (score 1):

There is [OAuth for Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/support.html).  The site has links to tutorial as well as sample project, which uses both OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0.  No idea how it can be used in grails though:(

Comment: Yup, seen it but no grails integration, thats the problem :(

Answer (score 1):

This exists, but there is no documentation, and I couldn't figure out how to use it.

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-oauth-provider

Answer (score 0):

If a bit of Java doesn't scare you, I would take a look at this: http://www.springsource.org/spring-social

It has a [demo site](https://greenhouse.springsource.org/) too

This project uses much of the same technology as Grails does under the hood. All sources are available for you to read. I have the same task coming up for my current Grails project and this is where I'll go for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an actively developed plugin for FaceBook that integrates with the spring security core plugin

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook

There are similar plugins for Twitter, etc.